# Docker container with git-sync returns Host key verification failed when doing git fetch

Tags: git, docker, airflow, git-sync

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
gitsync:
    image: openweb/git-sync:0.0.1
    restart: always
    command: >
      sh -c "ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa &&
             ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts &&
             chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa &&
             chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
    environment:
      GIT_SYNC_REPO: git@github.com:{company}/{repo_name}.git
      GIT_SYNC_DEST: /opt/airflow/dags/my_folder
      GIT_SYNC_BRANCH: master
      GIT_SYNC_SSH: 1
      GIT_SSH_KEY_FILE: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      GIT_SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    volumes:
    - ./database_utils:/database_utils
    - ./maintenance:/maintenance
    - ./utils:/utils
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

The error that I get is:

```
2022/02/02 16:29:36 error syncing repo: error running command "git fetch origin master": exit status 128: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repository exists because that `docker-compose.yml` worked when the content was setup to do it through `https`:

```
gitsync:
    image: openweb/git-sync:0.0.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      GIT_SYNC_REPO: https://{user}:{personal-access-token}@github.com/{company}/{repo_name}.git
      GIT_SYNC_DEST: /opt/airflow/dags/my_folder
      GIT_SYNC_BRANCH: master
    volumes:
    - ./database_utils:/database_utils
    - ./maintenance:/maintenance
    - ./utils:/utils
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

I tried to setup the grants to 600 as I read otherwise the key won't be used. Any idea how to fix it?

**EDIT: test with dockerfile**

I changed `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
  gitsync:
    image: my-gitsync-image
    restart: always
    container_name: my-gitsync
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-gitsync
    environment:
      GIT_SYNC_REPO: git@github.com:{company}/{repo}.git
      GIT_SYNC_DEST: /opt/airflow/dags/my_folder
      GIT_SYNC_BRANCH: master
      GIT_SYNC_SSH: 1
      GIT_SSH_KEY_FILE: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      GIT_SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE: ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And created a `Dockerfile-gitsync` as:

```
FROM openweb/git-sync:0.0.1

    RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Now the error is:

```
2022/02/02 17:53:41 error syncing repo: error running command "git fetch origin master": exit status 128: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I guess that know known host is working but ssh key doesn't like it. I tried doing:

```
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C "my_company@email.com"
```

But doesn't work neither.

Comment: Does `ssh-keyscan` (and the entire `command`) run before `git fetch`?

Comment: Don't think so. I tried a different setup and the error has changed. I update the main post again

Comment: After `ssh-keygen` and before `git fetch` you have to upload the newly created public key to the Github account.

Comment: The `ssh-keygen` command will generate a *new* key-pair (public and private) into the selected files, but once generated, the public key must be given to the server Git host so that the server host will accept the client's public key (after verifying it). What step copies the newly generated public key to github?

Comment: thats right @torek. Thanks

Comment: did you get this to work? I'd like to swap from NFS to using git-sync

Comment: yes @trench it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa https://github.com/
getaddrinfo https://github.com/: Name or service not known
```

SSH doesn't know anything about `https://github.com/`. It must be just host, not an URL (not to say that SSH and HTTPS URL contradicts a bit, right?)

```
$ ssh-keyscan github.com
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-e47cd09f
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-e47cd09f
github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-e47cd09f
github.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-e47cd09f
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-e47cd09f
```

Comment: you are right, doesnt make sense. Despite chaning it the issue stills there with the same error trace. I update the main post.